# Picture size in Android

Tags: java, android, image

I just got a question . I see many quiz apps in the appstore and Im asking myself how these apps have a size of 2-5 mb ... I mean when I put a jpg or png file in the projekt folder my apk gets for exampel 4 mb bigger ... Are they compressing the pictures or are they using a diffrent technic ? Am I able to show the pictures above the internet? For example pictures which are uploaded to a ftp server ..

Thank you for your answers

Maybe the question is too naiv I dont know ;)

Answer (score 0):

They are most likely compressing the images. When you package your app, there are different folders for different screen sizes and you put the corresponding images fit for those screens in those folders.

[See Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)